# Avocado plant with brown spots on the leaves

Tags: diagnosis, avocado, damage

[image]
My avocado has developed brown spots on the leaves trying to figure out what it is

Answer (score 1):

I'm definitely not an expert but it looks to me like too much fertilizer - that's what happened to my plant, it looked the same, brown spots between leave veins.